# Are there any retrieval systems out there?

Tags: video, information-retrieval, multimedia

I am looking for a video retrieval system whose code is readily available so that I can examine it. Moreover, I am looking for any relevant documentation about it.

The app will run locally. I will have a local folder of video, so i do not need a database. The language can be C++,C, or Java.

Basically, when i run the app, i should be able to select a video from the local storage of my computer. Now, the app should find similar videos in my "database" of videos and display them (preferably also give me the option to play them)

Comment: From where is this video retrieved and where is it sent? Streaming required?

Comment: @mrtsherman: I can have a local database of videos on my computer. The system will be run locally

Comment: Maybe you should give more background about what you are trying to do. I don't think this question is answerable in its current form. You have a local database, I assume it contains paths as storing actual video in a db would be inefficient. You want to do something locally... in what language? To accomplish what? From a webpage, from a video player, from a c# application???

Comment: @AndyT: suppose i search for soccer, the system should use both text and content based retrieval to return videos related to soccer. By content based, i mean return videos that maybe have a person playing soccer

Comment: Have You tried googling for "pattern recognition algorithm" ?

Answer (score 1):

try these : http://elinux.org/DLNA_Open_Source_Projects

Comment: And which out "these" answers my question

Answer (score 0):

Since a video is a sequence of frames (images) maybe you could extract some frames and compared them using [phash](http://www.phash.org).

As I understand the technique you want to use is [Video fingerprinting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_video_fingerprinting), but this is not an easy task, since you need to extract and save information for every video in order to search it. 
As far as I know there aren't any opensource libraries you can use... maybe you can bug some commercial provider one trial license to test.